# Как переопределить положение фиксированного элемента с неявно заданными размерами?

Tags: css, frontend, position

Есть блок с фиксированным позиционированием, высота которого определятся содержимым. Его обычное положение - низ страницы.

Возможно ли **добавить** к нему какие-то свойства, так чтобы он прикрепился к верху страницы и при этом сохранял свои размеры с учетом содержимого?

https://jsfiddle.net/LightFlight/4z0bzpjL/2/

```js
$('.lorem').click(function() {
 $(this).toggleClass('to-top');
});
```

```css
.lorem {
    width: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: red;
}

.to-top {
    /* bottom: none; ????  :) */
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="lorem">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте значение свойства bottom: [inherit](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_inherit.asp);

```
.to-top {
    top: 0;
    bottom: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Лучше bottom:auto.